# OpenLayers, valid zoom levels are offset by 1 level. Why?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have an OpenLayers based web app, map object is initialized like this:

```
p4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
p3857 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3857');

//initialize map object, bind it to map_canvas div
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_canvas', 
    {
    //allOverlays: true,
    projection: p3857,
    displayProjection: p4326,
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.3427892,-20037508.3427892,20037508.3427892,20037508.3427892), 
    numZoomLevels:20, 
    maxResolution:156543.0339,
    units:'m', 
    projection: p3857});
```

I have a pre-rendered map from levels 8-16, however, in order to view zoom level 16 of the map, I have to initialize its layer like this:

```
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("OSM Mapnik", "http://localhost/osm_tiles/osm/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", { isBaseLayer: true, sphericalMercator: true, numZoomLevels: 17});
map.addLayer(osm);
```

Notice, that I set the **zoom level 17** (or I can't zoom and view level 16 of the map). Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Does your backend support it? The rendering server needs to be setup accordingly!

Comment: Rendering was ok. I ll check what are the values of map object with firebug

Comment: need to count up from 0 so 17 will equal zoom level 16. (it is part of the api not because your tiles are starting from level 8).

Comment: @mapperz: thanks, i forgot i should consider the argument as index